# Time_tag in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In time_tag, i want to show the AM or PM of the time.
How to customize the helper.Since default time_tag is displaying **April 15, 2012 10:55**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

%p is the format token to show AM/PM

```
time_tag(time, :format=>'%B %d, %Y %l:%M %p')
```